# Large map of Africa, tiled printing on A3

Tags: cartography, printing, atlas

I would like to print a large map of Africa on several A3-pages. I want to hang the map on the wall. So the different pages should overlap a minimum.

The map will be used as a road map, so it should have the highest resolution possible, but consist of 5x7 A3-pages. (A3 is the largest format my printer can handle.) How do I print my map into tiled A3 pages with little overlap?

I am currently using QGIS and OSM-data, but other solutions are more than welcome.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. If you take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), you'll see that comments exist for others to request clarifications. If you have anything to add, it should be done by using the **edit** button beneath the question body. Please edit the question to specify what GIS software and data you are using to make this map series.

Comment: What have you tried, and what part are you stuck on? Are you unable to make QGIS print anything?  Or are you unsure how to zoom/pan around to print each area?  Or are you wanting some kind of automated way to print your pages?  Please [edit] your question to include more info about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you are meaning to use the atlas plug-in for multiple page printing. there is a good answer here at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199369/printing-map-on-several-pages-in-qgis?rq=1