# Printing large map in QGIS in normal paper size (A4, LEGAL)

Tags: qgis, print-composer

How do I print a large map in A4 size like "Tile printing"method where you can automatically divide that large map into equal parts(A4) then join it later by pasting?

I tried ATLAS plugin but it gives me different output, it divides the large map into A4 size but it has big overlaps in every A4 paper it produced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the layout paper size is big like `A1` or `A0` size, you need to adjust the paper size under the `Composition Tab` on Print composer to select the desired size:

[image]

When you adjust all element to fit the new paper size, export your map as PDF of A0 (for example), and open Acrobat reader and do the following:

- Open the exported layout
- Go to `Print -> Properties -> Select A4 size paper`
- Select `Poster`
- Adjust the `Tile Scale` and `Overlap`
- Check the `Cut mark`

[image]

Now you can print out the entire A0 size layout on multiple A4 sizes that each A4 page represents a portion of the A0. After finishing all printing process, you need to cut the overlapping portion using a cutter then merge all the A4 sheets.

You have to be careful when you cut, so you need first to check how the papers overlap each other.

Comment: If he want a scaled A4, I think this not good way. Try to make grid map of your extend, in print composer make atlas and use that grid to export scaled A4 maps. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199369/printing-map-on-several-pages-in-qgis/199412#199412

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ahmadhanb it help me alot!.. but im wonsering if there are available plugins in qgis that can perform this?thanks

Comment: @GridZone I am not aware of any plugin that can perform what you want, but this is what I do if I want to print large size layouts on small size papers. Another option that you can refer to link refered by nagib and see if that link helps you.

Comment: @nagib Thanks for the link, but actually it works as I explained in my answer. My answer might work if I am using numbers as a scale like 1: xxxx scale. But if I am using scale bar, the scale bar will be scaled also when re-scaling the maps on multiple papers. But your solution is also great.

Comment: @ ahmadhanb: i tried your tutorial and it works great but i notice that the scale of map is smaller when printed in .pdf. it looks like it was compress. how to print the actual size as it was made? thanks.

Comment: @GridZone I think the problem that when you adjust the paper size from A4 or A3 to A0 you did not adjust the scale. You need to adjust the scale also because the paper size was changed. To adjust the scale you need to select the Map Frame, under `Items` adjust the `Scale` value. You may need to adjust also the scale bar size by selecting the `<scale bar>` then modify the `Segments` units (1000 unit) or more or less (it is up to you) as long as the unit is Meters or any desired unit. If you did not update the scale after resizing the paper, I think it will look small.