# How to create multiple maps that once printed can be sticthed together in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping

I have a map of a parish which I can print as A1 at say 1:25000 scale.

However, if I want to close in on the same area at say 1:5000 scale, then how can I then create different maps in that parish area in a logically way that once printed can then be put together to create an even larger map of the parish at the improved scaling?

The link in the answer previously posted is extremely useful.  However, this does not quite answer my question. The link shows how to produce multiple A4 that can be put together to create an A1 size, but this is at the same scaling.  I wish to take that same parish area broken into sections scaled at say 1:5000 (i.e. on my screen is now a smaller part of the parish) but each section of this wider area is at A1 size so I end up with a super sized map of A1s placed together.

How can I split that parish layer to individual sections to create maps?

Comment: This question was already asked, please check this link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260199/how-to-print-large-map-in-qgis-in-normal-paper-sizea4-legal

Comment: I don't yet see the difference to the question linked above. Can you give a quick screen-grab example or something?