# Automatic extraction of a WMS screenshot, for each cell of a vector grid

Tags: qgis, wms, aerial-photography, offline

I am using a series of high-resolution aerial pictures, loaded through various WMS services in QGIS. I overlaid a vector grid and I would like to count specific landscape features in each cell. However, I am interested in work offline and therefore I was thinking about extracting the screenshot of each cell of the grid. Is there an automated way to do so in QGIS/GRASS?

[image]

Comment: I think this can help you. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199369/printing-map-on-several-pages-in-qgis/199412#199412

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [Atlas](https://gisgeography.com/how-to-create-qgis-atlas-mapbooks/):

1. Create a new print layout
2. Set page size to Custom and specify a square size
3. Add a map covering the entire page
4. Go to Atlas settings and:

- Check generate an atlas
- Coverage layer: Your grid layer
- Hidden
- Uncheck single file export ...
- set Image export format (I use tif)

5. Map 1 Item properties tab:

- Set controlled by atlas
- Predifined scale (best fit)

6. Layout tab: Set export dpi

Then go to Export Atlas as Images (in the top toolbar), set export resolution

A raster file will be created for each of your cover layer feature/grid cell